# What is the importance of the numbers inside the brackets in visual GC plugin?

Tags: garbage-collection, visualvm, jvisualvm

In the visual GC plugin of visualVM, there are some numbers mentioned inside the brackets for Eden Space, Survivor, Old Gen and Metaspace.
[image]
Kindly explain the importance of these numbers and if possible, the other contents as well including the Compile Time, Class Loader Time contents and the importance of Histogram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [visualgc tool page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/visualgc-136680.html):

> The title bar displays the name of the space and its maximum and current capacity in parenthesis followed by the current utilization of the space.

Note that you can also see the ratio between maximum and current capacity (=committed memory) in the “spaces” section, indicated by the brightness of the background grid (except for the survivor spaces, which may indicate that dynamic resizing is enabled).

The linked page also explains the other views.